# volumes_from tried to find a service despite container: is specified

Tags: docker-compose

I am running Win10, WSL and Docker Desktop. I have the following test YML which errors out:

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  cli:
    image: smartsheet-www
    volumes_from:
      - container:amazeeio-ssh-agent
➜  ~  ✗ docker-compose -f test.yml up
no such service: amazeeio-ssh-agent
```

Why does it try to find a *service* when I specified `container:` ?

The container exists, runs and has a volume.

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .Config.Volumes }}"  amazeeio-ssh-agent
map[/tmp/amazeeio_ssh-agent:{}]
docker exec -it amazeeio-ssh-agent /bin/sh -c 'ls -l /tmp/amazeeio_ssh-agent/'
total 0
srw-------    1 drupal   drupal           0 Apr  1 03:54 socket
```

Removing the volumes_from and the following line starts the `cli` service just fine.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching, I finally found https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8874 and https://github.com/pygmystack/pygmy-legacy/issues/60#issue-1037009622 this fixes it.

[uncheck this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S5t6.png)